# What things/attributes need to be changes while renaming a Site Defination?

Tags: 2007, publishing-site, xml, site-definition

I have a site definition folder with following structure,

- XML
- default.aspx
- MasterPage.master
- masterpageajax.master

In XML folder I have "ONET.XML" and I looked into this file, and realized that there isn't any GUID ID in it, just four section and a title, was wondering if changing the title gonna solve the problem for me or not ?

Structure of ONET.XML

```
<xml....>
<project Title ....>
<Navbars>
<ListTemplates>
<DocumentTemplates>
<Configuration>
<Modules>
<serverEmailFooter>
</project>
```

All i see is Title that I can change :S

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the naming of a Site Definition is in the webtempXXX.xml file in

> 12HIVE\TEMPLATE\1033\XML

See [How to: Create a Custom Site Definition and Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454677%28v=office.12%29.aspx)